# CTRL+C on 200k files aws s3 sync

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm syncing a directory containing 200k files (140GB) to a bucket using the following command

```
aws s3 sync target s3:/awesomebucket/key/prefix/ --region ap-southeast-2
```

I took along time. The network was not so fast. And it barely upload 5GB files.

[Ouput Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgHoP.png)

If I CTRL+C on the console, what is the consequences? Will it continue the progress when I re-run the program?

Answer (score 1):

Best guess is it will stop, and there may be a partially uploaded file, but that should get removed. I wouldn't expect any repercussion or problems. Try parallel uploads if latency is your issue.